# leaving the uiswitch on

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiswitch

I think  i have followed the instructions for leaving the uiswith on or off after someone has logged in or out of the app. I know i am missing something... 
Also on the

However it is not saving.  Also I don't get any errors compiling, just when i switch views, it looses the stored value.

Thank you in advance

```
-(IBAction)hintsPressed:(UISwitch *)sender {
    BOOL value = [sender isOn];
    [((FirstAppAppDelegate*)MI_SHARED_DELEGATE) setHintsOnorOff:&value];

    if ([((FirstAppAppDelegate*)MI_SHARED_DELEGATE) hints]==NO) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:hintsOnOff];

    }else if([((FirstAppAppDelegate*)MI_SHARED_DELEGATE) hints]==YES) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:hintsOnOff];
    }
}
```

Comment: i can not getting your actual question please specify more

Comment: why are you passing the bool value as &value, why don't you send it just like value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lines of code

```
-(IBAction)hintsPressed:(UISwitch *)sender 
{
   BOOL value = [sender isOn];
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value] forKey:hintsOnOff];
   [defaults synchronize];
}
```

May this will solve your problem :)

Comment: WOW.... that just made me feel dumb... haha thanks.  I guess it's part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// your code, [defaults setValue: ...

[defaults synchronize];
```

It's that last step that persists the defaults.